# div container and iframe auto height

Tags: html, css, height

I have been searching for similar approaches but still not found any solution to set the height of a div to automatically adjust it depending of the window size (i.e. when a window size is smaller, the height of the div container and the iframe inside should be adjusted accordingly)
Currently the iframe content is adjusted, but the div height size remains.
This is the simple code I have in the css:

```
#outerdiv
{
width:100%;
height:220px;
min-height:100px;
overflow:hidden;
border-style:solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#inneriframe
{
position:absolute;
top:--0px;
left:-0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

And this is the code in the html:

```
<div id='outerdiv'>
<iframe src="http://sampleiframe.org" id='inneriframe' scrolling=no frameborder="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Just to add that related div is acting as footer of this html and this is why I would like to auto adjust the height as currently when window size is reduced, this div container takes a good portion of the page.

Thanks in advance.

This is what I have added just before the above html lines:

```
<script>
function() {
  "use strict";

  var page = document.querySelector('#outerdiv'),
    height = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    frame = document.querySelector('#inneriframe');

  page.style.height = height + 'px';
  frame.style.height = height + 'px';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is your code with HTML, CSS and JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  #outerdiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  #inneriframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: --0px;
    left: -0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='outerdiv'>
    <iframe src="http://sampleiframe.org" id='inneriframe' scrolling=no frameborder="no"></iframe>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      "use strict";

      var page = document.querySelector('#outerdiv'),
        height = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        frame = document.querySelector('#inneriframe');

      page.style.height = height + 'px';
      frame.style.height = height + 'px';
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just changed, but div height still the same when the windows size is smaller, so as result the iframe is showed on the top part of the div container and the botton part empty.

Comment: It's weird. I have it working in all proportions and screen sizes. F5?

Comment: Yep, it is. I have been working around this for a while with different approaches and it seems to reject the solution hehe. I cleaned cache etc for testing and same behaviour. By the way, this is the most closed approach for the solution, but still pending the auto height adjustment...

Comment: your code was right! the issue I had was due to the page embedded in the iframe as there was a top margin that I haven't spoted. So thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var page = document.querySelector('#outerdiv'),
    height = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    frame = document.querySelector('#inneriframe');

  page.style.height = height + 'px';
  frame.style.height = height + 'px';
})();
```

Comment: give a little more explanation - it avoids the OP never learning by copying and pasting, with an explanation they'll understand the why a lot more, leading to less questions on SO  ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Mishutin. I have added this as script just before the above html lines but still the same..

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS we can achieve by mentioning height in percentage.

```
#outerdiv
{
  width:100%;
  height:40%;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-style:solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ujjwala but I tried  this approach before raise te question because this doesn't resolve at all the issue. Applying this, the iframe got dropped when the window size is smaller and cannot see the full content